# WPF reporting control that integrates well with MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reporting

Is there any WPF control (commercial or not) that integrates well with the MVVM pattern ?
Ideally the report would be another View for the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from another answer here on SO (thought it was a bit old), [this open-source solution](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/) was suggested. The page states that it's alpha, though.

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/reporting.aspx#Overview) has a solution, as does [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ReportsWPF/).

[[sources]](http://www.google.com/search?gfns=1&q=wpf+reporting)

Comment: after a closer look wpfreports.codeplex.com disappointed me, it only supports DataSets as data source, not object graphs as I would liked